# How to process batchUpdate and copy from one spreadsheet into another using Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

Link to original question where I found the below script: [How to batch-copy range with Google Sheets Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196252/how-to-batch-copy-range-with-google-sheets-api)

**Question:** How do I modify the below to write into a different spreadsheetId? I've Googled everything I can and can only find examples where the copyPaste occurs within the same SpreadsheetID.

```
function Test_Copy() {
  var spreadsheetId = "1hLXq9zq-tAaGpPtGiY6859h4oKxIbNimxCHPPZOzdE0";
  var sheetId = "1792457718";
  var sheetIdd = "760382355";

  var rangeFrom = Sheets.newGridRange();
  rangeFrom.sheetId = sheetId;
  rangeFrom.startRowIndex = 0;
  rangeFrom.endRowIndex = 23637;  
  rangeFrom.startColumnIndex = 0;
  rangeFrom.endColumnIndex = 23;

  var rangeTo = Sheets.newGridRange();
  rangeTo.sheetId = sheetIdd;
  rangeTo.startRowIndex = 0;
  rangeTo.endRowIndex = 23637;  
  rangeTo.startColumnIndex = 0;
  rangeTo.endColumnIndex = 23;  


var copyPasteRequest = Sheets.newCopyPasteRequest();
  copyPasteRequest.destination =  rangeTo;    
  copyPasteRequest.source =  rangeFrom;
  copyPasteRequest.pasteType = "PASTE_VALUES";
  copyPasteRequest.pasteOrientation = "NORMAL";

  var resource = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();

  //Create request object
  var request = Sheets.newRequest();
  request.copyPaste = copyPasteRequest;
  resource.requests = [request];

  var res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource , spreadsheetId);
  //Logger.log(res.replies);
  //Logger.log(res.spreadsheetId);

}
```

Comment: Why not using the [Method: spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo)? Also, are you using Apps Script? If so, you could use the [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) from SpreadsheetsApp

Comment: Hi Kessy - Sorry, I should have noted. The sheet I make a copy of is created by a =QUERY({}) formula. If I use copyTo(), it won't send the values into the new spreadsheet. Either way, I can't use copyTo() because the spreadsheet I send it to has formula dependencies and would be a pain to update each formula to use the new sheet.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to solve it? If not, what do you mean on `the spreadsheet I send it to has formula dependencies`?

Comment: In my 2nd spreadsheet (target spreadsheet) I have formulas in a different tab which reference the data I'm trying to bring in from the source. I'm looking for a way to just push an update to the existing sheet rather than performing copyTo() which would create a new tab and require me to change the formulas to reference the new tab instead. @Kessy - Apologies for this late reply!